# Swift - Sorting array of objects by another array's property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, object

I want to sort an Array of objects, by the properties it shares with another Array of objects

```
    struct GeneralComposition : Decodable {
        let id, formId, relationId, fixedContentTypeId, separatorId: Int
        let orderBy: Int

    }
    struct FixedContentType: Decodable {
        let name, htmlType: String
        let isEditable: Int
        let typeId : String


    }



   var fixedContentType = [FixedContentType]()
   var generalComposition = [GeneralComposition]()
```

In `GeneralComposition` I get the order the items must have, with `orderBy`, and then take every item's `fixedContentTypeID`, compare with the `typeId` in `FixedContentType` to get the order in which this content must be showed in screen.

Any idea about how can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Can you show us how do you want to get an output?

Comment: @matt - That looks like a duplicate, but isn’t quite the same. That `indexOf` pattern is not applicable here.

Comment: Cosorting is cosorting it seems to me. It’s not like it’s never been discussed before.

Comment: Maybe, we can find a consorting example where it’s not relying on the `index(of:)` the identifier in the second array, but rather a property of the objects in that second array, like this one. I looked and one didn’t jump out at me, but I bet there’s one out there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a dictionary for the `fixedContentTypeID`’s of `generalComposition`:

```
let order = generalComposition.reduce(into: [Int: Int]()) { result, value in
    result[value.fixedContentTypeId] = value.orderBy
}
```

You now have an efficient way to lookup the `orderBy` value for a given `typeId` within your array of `FixedContentType` objects. You can use that for sorting:

```
fixedContentType.sort {
    (order[$0.typeId] ?? 0) < (order[$1.typeId] ?? 0)
}
```

---

By the way, your `typeId` is a `String`, and `fixedContentTypeId` is an `Int`. I’m assumed that was a typo introduced when preparing the question, and that they’re really both `Int`. If they’re really different types (which would be weird), the solution would be similar, though you’d have to do some conversions. But I didn’t want to go there unless you confirmed that this is really what you model was.

But, given that your `typeId` really is a `String`, you could make your dictionary a `[String: Int]`:

```
let order = generalComposition.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { result, value in
     result[String(value.fixedContentTypeId)] = value.orderBy
}
```

Comment: What about a protocol ?

Comment: make protocol that have the shared properties and an array of this protocol and sort that ?

Comment: I’d suggest you post you own answer showing how you’d propose using a protocol. I personally don’t see how that would help. The main thrust of my answer is using a dictionary to achieve O(1) performance for the retrieval of the `orderBy` values.

Comment: if i wanted to answer i would've i want to know the difference and gain exp from the high tier ^_^ thanks anyway

Comment: one day i will care about the O(1), just like you do sir.

Comment: thanks @Rob, I think this is close to be what I need, but unfortunately, they actually are different values. 'typeId' is a String which is a number, I get all this data from an API and datas come like this... So now I need to find the way to make those conversions

Comment: @ManuelLagunaMatias - I’ve revised my answer showing how you’d save the keys of that dictionary as `String` instances. But I’d really suggest fixing that API (or reaching out to whomever is maintaining that codebase) because it’s obviously internally inconsistent.